# "Tamp down" vs "clamp down"

Tags: word-choice, idioms

In [this article by the Houston Chronicle](http://www.chron.com/news/houston-texas/article/Houston-protest-leaders-say-they-re-being-10621826.php) we see

> "It is my belief we are in the middle of a **police campaign to tamp down on demonstration and protest after the election**," Harrison said

It looked like a typo, but ["tamp down"](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/tamp-down) seems to exist.

> **tamp down** - to reduce the amount, level, size, or importance of something: As the price of gasoline rose above $3 a gallon, consumers cut their spending elsewhere, tamping down profits in retail, travel and other industries.
>   The party retained power by boosting the economy and tamping down corruption.

I always *hear* "clamp down" though. Which is correct?

Comment: I think *tamping* relates more to reducing the amount of something, while *clamping* is used in a restrictive way by a force such as the police. I would personally use *clamp* here, although this may be a transatlantic-difference.

Comment: What Bladorthin says. And I've never seen *tamp down **on***. I think this is an error, a confusion of two idioms.

Comment: I think tamp could be used correctly in this instance, assuming that the police meant it in a way that did not include forcing the reduction or restriction.

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey we need someone who speaks funny so they can clear up any potential transatlantic difference.

Comment: *Tamping* is what you do with your feet or some sort of [tamper](https://www.grainger.com/product/1MDW6?gclid=CjwKEAiA6rrBBRDsrLGM4uTPkWASJADnWZQ4MESd0YTQIXFA-PPHc4rx0O9SnlbgWSu02XSZLCatixoCHQzw_wcB&cm_mmc=PPC:GOOGLEPLAA-_-Outdoor%20Equipment-_-Shovels%2C%20Tampers%2C%20and%20Digging%20Tools-_-1MDW6&AL!2966!3!56542795677!!!s!104636126997!&s_kwcid=AL!2966!3!56542795677!!!s!104636126997!&ef_id=V2-MCQAAAXv-qPRn:20161118202533:s).

Comment: I talk funny in a variety of  accents--*clamp down on* is the usual US euphemism for "suppress" in these contexts

Comment: Actually, "tamp down" is not necessarily an error in the above.  "Clamp down" implies squeezing tightly in one location, while "tamp down" means to apply a little pressure here, a little pressure there, across a wide area.  (Stomping on a fire, as it were.)

Comment: If a party can "tamp down corruption" then the police can "tamp down protest".

Comment: (The error in the original statement is using "on" -- one does not "tamp down on" something but rather one would "tamp down" something.

Comment: Both expressions are, on some level, metaphors--each invokes a physical action to symbolize a social one.  From their physical meanings, I personally interpret "clamp down" (to secure something by tightening it between the jaws of a clamp) as implying a more forceful action than to "tamp down" (to compress something by repeated application of weight).  But either could apply.

Comment: These aren't really comments they're answers. Vote the question and up vote the right answer, or submit your own.

Answer (score 2):

To *tamp* is to compress, from one side or direction. The result of tamping something, or tamping something down, is make that something have a smaller height or volume (which makes it more dense).

Workers with asphalt sometimes use a *tamp* (a pole with a perpendicular, flat steel base) to *tamp* down the earth or gravel under new asphalt.  And after they apply asphalt on top of it they then *tamp* the asphalt itself, to make it smooth and compact.

Tamping has nothing to do with *clamping*. The first quotation you cite uses *tamp* incorrectly, IMO (it should use *clamp* instead). You do not *tamp* down **on** something (well, you do, but that's not the expression you use). However, to *clamp down on* something is a common expression.

Comment: Insofar as "tamping down" implies compression it is an apt way to describe the the police campaign tactic of applying force to contain the demonstrations.

Comment: @ErinJohnLevins: It is the *on* that sounds odd (to me). *The moderator tried to tamp down the crowd's anger* sounds right. *The police tried to tamp down the demonstration* might be OK. But that they tried to *tamp down **on*** it does not sound right (to me).